# Not able to fetch result at output in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am working on cakephp project related to rooms and hotels and it has four lists 
`hotel, xyz, abx, qwe`

where `hotel` and `xyz` is able to view reult on search button with google location and `abx` and `qwe` are unable to view result at output. What can be the error and how can it be diagnosed.

Answer (score 0):

set different roles for user,and when fetch result apply user role in conditions.this will resolve your issues.